# Translate formula to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have translated this formula to VBA for use as a variable with the FollowHyperlink method:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(Sites[Base], MATCH([@Site], Sites[Site], 0)), "*", [@Variable])
```

How can I refer to `Selection.Offset(0, -1)` by the column's name (in case the table structure changes)?

```
Dim sSite As String
If Not Intersect(Target, tb.ListColumns("Variable").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True
    sSite = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Sites[[Base]]") _
    , WorksheetFunction.Match(Selection.Offset(0, -1), Range("Sites[[Site]]"), 0)), "*", "" & ActiveCell.Value & "")
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (sSite)
End If
```

Also, how can I deal with the case where there is no Site? This is not limited to the Variable column:

```
If Intersect(Target, tb.ListColumns("Variable").DataBodyRange) <> "" And Selection.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
```

Comment: Have you try recording your macro?

Comment: Assuming that you know the column layout of your own table, why don't you hard-code the offsets and use VBA to make the replacement? Structured listobject table addressing is a pain in VBA.

Answer (score -1):

You can record it to create a vba code in your macro. Cut your formula first then click Record in Developer Tab, then paste the formula back. Stop the recording and click Visual Basic, in Module1,  you will see the generated code with a method name `Macro1`.

Comment: I don't this isn't going to help within a Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick with Target.